# Configuration of JDBC Sink Connector in KsqlDB from MySQL database to PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, ksqldb

I wanted to copy a table from MySQL database to PostgreSQL. I have KsqlDB which acts as a stream processor. For the start, I just want to copy a simple table from the source's 'inventory' database to the sink database (PostgreSQL). The following is the structure of inventory database:

```
mysql> show tables;
+---------------------+
| Tables_in_inventory |
+---------------------+
| addresses           |
| customers           |
| geom                |
| orders              |
| products            |
| products_on_hand    |
+---------------------+
```

I have logged into the KsqlDB and register a source connector using the following configuration

```
CREATE SOURCE CONNECTOR inventory_connector WITH (
'connector.class' = 'io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector',
'database.hostname' = 'mysql',
'database.port' = '3306',
'database.user' = 'debezium',
'database.password' = 'dbz',
'database.allowPublicKeyRetrieval' = 'true',
'database.server.id' = '223344',
'database.server.name' = 'dbserver',
'database.whitelist' = 'inventory',
'database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers' = 'broker:9092',
'database.history.kafka.topic' = 'schema-changes.inventory',

'transforms' = 'unwrap',
'transforms.unwrap.type'= 'io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope',     
'key.converter'= 'org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter',
'key.converter.schemas.enable'= 'false',
'value.converter'= 'org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter',
'value.converter.schemas.enable'= 'false'
);
```

The following are the topics created

```
ksql> LIST TOPICS;

 Kafka Topic                         | Partitions | Partition Replicas
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 _ksql-connect-configs               | 1          | 1
 _ksql-connect-offsets               | 25         | 1
 _ksql-connect-statuses              | 5          | 1
 dbserver                            | 1          | 1
 dbserver.inventory.addresses        | 1          | 1
 **dbserver.inventory.customers**        | 1          | 1
 dbserver.inventory.geom             | 1          | 1
 dbserver.inventory.orders           | 1          | 1
 dbserver.inventory.products         | 1          | 1
 dbserver.inventory.products_on_hand | 1          | 1
 default_ksql_processing_log         | 1          | 1
 schema-changes.inventory            | 1          | 1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I need to just copy the contents of the 'dbserver.inventory.customers' to the PostgreSQL database. The following are the structure of the data

```
ksql> PRINT 'dbserver.inventory.customers' FROM BEGINNING;
Key format: JSON or HOPPING(KAFKA_STRING) or TUMBLING(KAFKA_STRING) or KAFKA_STRING
Value format: JSON or KAFKA_STRING
rowtime: 2022/08/29 02:39:20.772 Z, key: {"id":1001}, value: {"id":1001,"first_name":"Sally","last_name":"Thomas","email":"sally.thomas@acme.com"}, partition: 0
rowtime: 2022/08/29 02:39:20.773 Z, key: {"id":1002}, value: {"id":1002,"first_name":"George","last_name":"Bailey","email":"gbailey@foobar.com"}, partition: 0
rowtime: 2022/08/29 02:39:20.773 Z, key: {"id":1003}, value: {"id":1003,"first_name":"Edward","last_name":"Walker","email":"ed@walker.com"}, partition: 0
rowtime: 2022/08/29 02:39:20.773 Z, key: {"id":1004}, value: {"id":1004,"first_name":"Anne","last_name":"Kretchmar","email":"annek@noanswer.org"}, partition: 0
```

I have tried the following configuration of the sink connector:

```
CREATE SINK CONNECTOR postgres_sink WITH (
        'connector.class'= 'io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector',
        'connection.url'= 'jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/inventory',
        'connection.user' = 'postgresuser',
        'connection.password' = 'postgrespw',
        'topics'= 'dbserver.inventory.customers',
        'transforms'= 'unwrap',
        'transforms.unwrap.type'= 'io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState',
        'transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones'= 'false',    
        'key.converter'= 'org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter',
        'key.converter.schemas.enable'= 'false',
        'value.converter'= 'org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter',
        'value.converter.schemas.enable'= 'false',
        'auto.create'= 'true',
        'insert.mode'= 'upsert',
        'auto.evolve' = 'true',
        'table.name.format' = '${topic}',
        'pk.mode'   = 'record_key',
        'pk.fields' =  'id',
        'delete.enabled'= 'true'
);
```

It creates the connector but shows the following errors:

```
ksqldb-server      | Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Sink connector 'POSTGRES_SINK' is configured with 'delete.enabled=true' and 'pk.mode=record_key' and therefore requires records with a non-null key and non-null Struct or primitive key schema, but found record at (topic='dbserver.inventory.customers',partition=0,offset=0,timestamp=1661740760772) with a HashMap key and null key schema.
```

What should be the configuration of the Sink Connector to copy these data to PostgreSQL?
I have also tried creating a stream first in AVRO and then using AVRO Key, Value convertor but it did not work. I think it is something to do with using right SMTs but I am not sure.

My ultimate aim is to join different streams and then store it in the PostgreSQL as a part of implementing the CQRS architecture. So if someone can share a framework I could use in such case it would be really useful.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, the key must be a primitive, not JSON object and not Avro either.

From your shown JSON, you'd need an extract field transform on your key

```
transforms=getKey,unwrap
transforms.getKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key
transforms.getKey.field=id
```

Or, you might be able to change your source connector to use IntegerConverter, not JSONConverter for the keys

Debezium also has an old blog post covering this exact use case - https://debezium.io/blog/2017/09/25/streaming-to-another-database/

Comment: Thank you @OneCriketeer. I have added the three configuration to my Sink Connector Configuration. However, I am still getting the following error: "Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Sink connector 'POSTGRES_SINK' is configured with 'delete.enabled=true' and 'pk.mode=record_key' and therefore requires records with a non-null key and non-null Struct or primitive key schema, but found record at (topic='dbserver.inventory.customers',partition=0,offset=0,timestamp=1661843227870) with a Long key and null key schema."